# Unit testing with XUnit

Tags: c#, moq, autofac, xunit.net

I'm implementing unit testing in my app with XUnit and I have autofac as my DI. The autofac documentaion recomends using Autofac.Extras.Moq.AutoMock. I'm completely new to this and have been following the documented examples but I can't get it to work properly. This is code I'm using to generate the test:

```
using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose())
{
    mock.Mock<IScheduleService>().Setup(m => m.GenerateSchedule(request)).Returns(response);
    var sut = mock.Create<ScheduleService>();
    var actual = sut.GenerateSchedule(request);
    mock.Mock<IScheduleService>().Verify(x => x.GenerateSchedule(request));
    Assert.Equal(response.Schedules, actual.Schedules);
}
```

The method under test basically returns a list of 'schedule' objects (dates & times) So I've mocked up a valid response which the method will return from its input. The method is invoked and the code runs and returns an object (list of schedules), but I get this error and the test fails

```
ApplicationService.Tests.Schedule.ScheduleServiceTest.TestDailyScheduleCreation [FAIL]
[xUnit.net 00:02:33.7051040]       Moq.MockException : 
Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: x => x.GenerateSchedule()
[xUnit.net 00:02:33.7089101]       
[xUnit.net 00:02:33.7096712]       Configured setups: 
[xUnit.net 00:02:33.7101336]       m => m.GenerateSchedule()
[xUnit.net 00:02:33.7134611]       No invocations performed.
```

I'm not really sure what's going on here as I've not used XUnit and Moq before, can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

heres the system under test

```
private List<ScheduleDto> CalculateDaily(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, TimeSpan GenerationTimeUTC, long scheduleId)
    {
        List<ScheduleDto> schedulesList = new List<ScheduleDto>();
        var numOfDays = (endDate - startDate).TotalDays;
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfDays ; i++)
        {
            ScheduleDto newSchedule = new ScheduleDto();
            newSchedule.GenerationDate = startDate.AddDays(i);
            newSchedule.GenerationTimeUTC = GenerationTimeUTC;
            newSchedule.ScheduleID = scheduleId;
            newSchedule.IsEmailed = false;
            newSchedule.IsGenerated = false;
            schedulesList.Add(newSchedule);
        }
            return schedulesList;
    }
```

this is the request object

```
ScheduleGenerationRequest request = new ScheduleGenerationRequest(0);
        CreateScheduleRequest response = new CreateScheduleRequest(0);

        request.StartDate = new DateTime(2017, 7, 17);
        request.EndDate = request.StartDate.AddDays(7);
        request.Frequency = EnumHelper.ScheduleFrequency.Daily;
        request.FrequencyPeriod = 1;
        TimeSpan timeSpan = new TimeSpan(19, 00, 00);
        request.GenerationTimeUTC = timeSpan;
```

this is the main method in the service class

```
public CreateScheduleRequest GenerateSchedule(ScheduleGenerationRequest request)
    {
        CreateScheduleRequest response = new CreateScheduleRequest(request.Id);
        List<ScheduleDto> result = new List<ScheduleDto>();
        switch (request.Frequency)
        {
            case EnumHelper.ScheduleFrequency.Daily:
                result = CalculateDaily(request.StartDate,request.EndDate, request.GenerationTimeUTC,request.Id);
                break;
            case EnumHelper.ScheduleFrequency.Weekly:
                result = CalculateWeekly(request.StartDate, request.EndDate, request.GenerationTimeUTC, request.Id, request.PrintDaySpecifier, request.FrequencyPeriod);
                break;
            case EnumHelper.ScheduleFrequency.Monthly:

                break;
            case EnumHelper.ScheduleFrequency.Yearly:

                break;
        }
        response.Schedules = result;
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: The line with `Verify` is actually unnecessary.. You're explicitly calling that method in the line before it so no need to verify it.

Comment: I should add that the system under test (sut) is invoked and the code runs though without a hitch this line is the issue    mock.Mock<IScheduleService>().Verify(x => x.GenerateSchedule(request));

Comment: How can the *System Under Test* be a mock ? This doesn't make much sense for me, mocks should be the collaborators that SUT uses.

Comment: thanks for the advice, Ive commented the line out, there is another issue though, the mocked and returned objects each have 7 items but the assert.equal is failing.  How do I actually compare them ?

Comment: OK, have I got this whole concept wrong ? I just want to unit test the ScheduleService, do I have to setup the dependency resolver in my test projects as well, I thought the mocking platform would do that for me

Comment: @proteus When testing the sut you mock the dependencies of the sut.

Comment: If you mock a method to return something, and then unit test that it is returning that thing then you're not testing your code. You're testing that the mocking framework works. I don't think this is what you're after. Think again about what behavior you're trying to test.

Comment: so in this instance, I pass a start and end date into the service, I then expect 7 dates to be returned, so I can check the count of the objects created, but what about the actual dates themselves ? do I have to cycle though each one and test it against a known value for the input ?

Comment: @proteus you will probably need to show the sut for us to get an idea of what it is you are testing.

Comment: Ive just added the system under test code

Comment: @proteus Where are you using `DI` is the class under test ? We can't see that. If you don't have any dependencies passed in the constructor (or properties maybe) then you don't need mocks at all.

Comment: there is another service that will eventually consume the one im testing, but i just wanted to test basic functionality before I implment that.  I read that its considered bad practice to setup the dependencies in your test code (as in my bootstrapper code), and that Moq was an accepted method, is this wrong ? do  have to include code like this each of my test classes ?     builder.RegisterType<ScheduleService>().As<IScheduleService>().InstancePerRequest();

Comment: I am new to this so please excuse my rookie questions :-)